# Does an extra non indexed argument with a clustered index in a where clause make it any less efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a clustered index (let's say on columns `a, b ,c`). Would it be just as fast if my where clause looked like

```
WHERE a = x 
  AND b = y 
  AND c = z
```

vs

```
WHERE a = x 
  AND b = y 
  AND c = z 
  AND d = w
```

where `d` is a column in that table that is not indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries would, in fact, have remarkably similar performance under most circumstances.  Both would have to scan all rows in the index with the matching a, b, and c values.  Typically, both queries would also have to scan the associated data pages as well.

I can readily think of two things that affect performance, and they could go either way.  If the first query only selects those three columns, then the clustered index is a *covering index* for the query, meaning that the data pages don't need to be accessed.  Then, adding the condition on `d` might slow the query down because of the extra access to data page(s).

Second, the volume for the second query is (presumably) smaller than the data for the first version.  This could speed up the query, particularly if other processing (say `group by` or `order by`) is involved.

Comment: You say "meaning that the data pages don't need to be accessed", but it is a clustered index. Wouldn't that mean the data pages are always accessed because the leafs are the records?

Comment: Only the leaves of the clustered index contain the records.  To satisfy the condition on `d` requires looking at the data pages.  Technically, you are correct in saying that the index is being used for this, because the leaves are the data pages. I'm making the distinction between the b-tree structure of the index and the data pages.